# How do I add Swap partition after the installation has been done?

Tags: swap, antergos

I recently dual booted my computer, Antergos (with Gnome) with existing Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 installation. and I noticed that Gnome shell in Antergos features a Hibernation button which was not present in Gnome shell with Ubuntu. But when I tried to click that button, my computer won't hibernate. I've a swap partition but currently Ubuntu installation is using it. I want that swap partition to be used by Antergos for hibernation purpose.

output of `lsblk` ran from Antergos

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   7.6G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  19.1G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0  47.7G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0  18.6G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0  18.8G  0 part /home
```

In the table above, `sda1` is swap `sda5` is /root for Ubuntu. `sda6` is /home for Ubuntu and `sda5 to sda8` are part of an extended partition.

keep in mind that my experience with anything that's based on Arch is too little (below 24 hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the swap partition that your ubuntu install is also using.

First, determine the UUID of the partition:

```
root@darkstar:~ # blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="1558f461-07af-47e5-a7ef-fe11a780f09f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0005e081-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="5c00b21d-4569-4a00-b419-fd86be1be6f6" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0005e081-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="00eff59f-b759-4b3f-94ef-3e8c0371e714" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cc26cc26-01"
```

So `/dev/sda2` is my swap, and the UUID is `5c00b21d-4569-4a00-b419-fd86be1be6f6`

Then add an entry in `/etc/fstab`:

`UUID=5c00b21d-4569-4a00-b419-fd86be1be6f6 none    swap  sw   0   0`

Then either reboot or run `swapon /dev/sda1`  or `swapon -a`

Comment: If the Antergos and Ubuntu installations share the swap partition, you have to keep in mind that you can't hibernate one system, start the other and expect to be able to resume the first system from hibernation.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I'm not planning to use it in Ubuntu